# accessing structure variable through pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
typedef struct male_node
{
    int mv1,mv2,mv3;
}male;

typedef struct movie_name
{
    char mvnm[20];
    struct male *ml;
}movie;

main()
{
    movie mov1;
    mov1.ml=(male*)malloc(sizeof(male));
    mov1.(*ml).mv1=1;//ERROR
    mov1.ml->mv1=1; //ERROR
}
```

How to access the mv1 variable through mov1 and ml
I tried to access mv1 through ml which is a pointer to a structure which is again a structure variable but it shows error.

Comment: Can you post what error is returning?

Comment: I know that you don't _have_ to put an `int` in front of `main` but it hurts my heart when I see it is missing.

Comment: Does modern C really still allow omitting return types?

Comment: @RobK: No, it's required now.

Answer (score 4):

This looks wrong:

```
struct male *ml;
```

You've used `typedef` to define `male` as `struct male_node`, so it doesn't make sense to say `struct male`. Instead, try this:

```
typedef struct movie_name
{
    char mvnm[20];
    male *ml;
} movie;
```

That should fix your problem, and you should be able to do this:

```
mov1.ml->mv1=1;
```

Comment: Thank You. Actually I did not noticed that. It now works fine.

Comment: and `mov1.(*ml).mv1=1;` to `(*mov1.ml).mv1=1;`